# ElasticSearch Multi Term Searching

Tags: elasticsearch

I have some documents stored in elastic and want to query them on serveral terms, with several possible values.

For example, the document is basically as follows:

```
[id] => 1
[title] => 'running shoes'
[parent_product_id] => 100
[brand_id] => 198
[category_id] => 3
```

I want to, for example, look for all products that fall under one of the categories 1, 2 and 3 and where the brand is either 198 or 245.

One product has only one category and only one brand , but I need the ability for search to accept multiples of both. So all products under 1 category but multiple brands, or one brand, under multiple categories, or multiple brands under multiple categories.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I have some documents stored in elastic and want to query them on serveral terms, with several possible values.

Please, read here: [How to combine filters](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/combining-filters.html), [How to combine queries](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/bool-query.html)

> I want to, for example, look for all products that fall under one of the categories 1, 2 and 3 and where the brand is either 198 or 245.

Try this:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_search?pretty' -d '{
    "filter": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "category_id": [1, 2, 3]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "brand_id": [198, 245]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}'
```